# Homebrew - Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins

Tags: docker, macos, homebrew

Homebrew gives me this error on macOS Monterey while using it:

```
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

As written here https://flaviocopes.com/homebrew-fix-permission-denied-apply2files/ ,

if you had recently deleted Docker, you have to manually recreate the Docker folder:

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins
```

Then run

```
brew cleanup
```

You should have fixed the issue!

After that, you can delete the Docker application inside the Application folder

Comment: `brew cleanup` gave me the same error

Comment: This temporarily fixes the issue, but after deleting Docker.app again, it re-appears. Instead, I deleted `sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins`, which was a symlink to that (non-existent) Docker.app subdirectory. More info here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009

Answer (score 32):

As noted by @JW, the accepted answer above...

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins
```

Then running

```
brew cleanup
```

Does not work for everyone (and did not work for me). What did work is what they suggested:

> Instead, I deleted sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins, which
> was a symlink to that (non-existent) Docker.app subdirectory.

Here is the code to run:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
```

As JW suggested, this link explains more: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009

Comment: This worked for me (MBP 2022, Ventura 13.2.1). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I tried the accepted solution, but it didn't work for me.

I finally resolved it with the following commands:

```bash
$ brew cleanup
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
$ brew doctor
...
Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
  /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
...
$ sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local/lib
$ brew cleanup
```

Answer (score 6):

## Problem

listing the file details

`ls -la /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins`

reveals that

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  55 Mar 22  2022 /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins`

- `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins` is a link (alias) to `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins`
- user `root` has the `w` write permission (also allows deletion during the cleanup)
- If you are not the `root` user, then you will see this issue

## Solution

Depends on what you need for your system

### recommended

If you do not have or need docker (just removed it maybe), then simply delete the link itself

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
```

Why `sudo`? because only `root` has access to that link, which you (current user, identified by `whoami`) are not. That is why you saw this error in the first place.

Why `-r`? because you want to remove the entire folder recursively.

### workaround #1

- create the destination folder temporarily
- brew cleanup
- remove the temporary folder

This also works if you are using docker, but accidentally removed `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins` folder, or changed permissions, then fix it by creating this folder again so that the link can point to an existing folder.

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins
brew cleanup
```

then

```
rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins
```

or, because you created the entire path which means you do not need `/Applications/Docker.app` anyways

```
rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app
```

### workaround #2

change permissions of the `lib` folder, recursively
Why? because `usr/local/lib` is anyways meant for the local user. You can gain access to it instead of `root` having exclusive access to any item.

refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout

`sudo chown -R "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local/lib`

*PS: there may be more ways to solve this issue, but removing the root cause is recommended.*